# An option to show only questions with a favorited tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, filtering

There is a preference to `hide ignored tags`, which is very helpful to weed out questions that I know nothing about.  But my `ignored tags` list keeps getting longer and longer as I try to hide tags/questions that get in the way of the ones that I really might be able to answer...

It would be very helpful to be able to `hide non-Favorite tags`.  This way I can mark tags that I have an interest in, and easily focus on related questions.

Of course, it would helpful to be able to easily toggle the `hide` on and off so that I can turn it off from time to time and see if there are other new tags that I should be watching.

Comment: "ignore non-favorite" can be reworded to "show only favorite" I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might get better mileage from selecting the interesting tags.

Something like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+javascript+or+forth
which yields:

[image: php javascript or forth]

and has the usual newest/featured/active tabs.

Comment: Excellent suggestion!